# Can you use javascript to halt the currently running c++ in WebAssembly?

Tags: javascript, c++, exit, webassembly

I have written a simulation in c++, and this has been compiled to wasm. The code is being called by javascript using ccall, and this all happens in a web worker. Some of the c++ subroutines take minutes/hours/days to run.

Is there a way I can use javascript to tell the WebAssembly module to cancel the current task? I have tried using a stopWebAssembly() function:

```
    void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE stopWebAssembly(){
        stop = true;
    }
    ...
    void simulate(){
        State* state = new State();
        while(!state->isTerminated() && !stop){
            // Perform operation on state

        }
    }
```

The intent was that calling stopWebAssembly() would cancel the simulation. But this does not work. Is there something else I can do? The best I can think of is to return back to the js after every thousand or so iterations of the while loop to see if javascript has requested to stop, but this seems inefficient and clumsy.

Comment: [No taglines please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Why would you have `stopWebAssembly` call `simulate`?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Fixed now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for your ‘stop’ variable to be set via JavaScript, the WebAssembly is going to have to yield execution - this means turning your long running computation into a series of small chunks that can be executed.

In future you might be able to use a SharedArrayBuffer as a way to communicate betwee the two, but this is dependent on the upcoming thread support in WebAssembly. See:

https://github.com/WebAssembly/design/issues/950